# How to place button in over a text in an imageview and maintain its postion in all screen resolution in xcode swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have an image of India map with the city name indicated. I need to make the city names clickable. I tried placing buttons over the city names. But these buttons are replaced on a different screen.[image: code]

Comment: What language are you using? What is the code you have written?

Comment: in xcode-using swift

Comment: Without knowing what your existing code looks like, this question will be too broad to receive good answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `UIView`(view) above the `UIButton` and your button(Gurgoan) top pin to the Button Pin to the view(means vertical distance) and 
then out the height of constraint to this view which is equal to the map Image
So when the map height will change the UIView height will change too.
With this you can manage the vertical position of the Gurgaon Text Button.

You can se the equal Height constraint multiplier according to you requirement.

the same way you to create the pin to the other buttons, the bottom position buttons will pin to the UIView from the bottom.

if the button which are in the center of image can hav the vertical centre 
and pin from either left or right.
Try this it will help.

Check the screenshots:

**Consttaints_iPhone11_Pro**

[image: uiview with constraints]

with **iPad_10.2 full screen**

[image: output on iPad_10.2 full screen]

with **iPad_10.2 2/3 screen ratio**

[image: output on iPad_10.2 2/3 portion screen]

with **iPad_12**

[image: output on iPad12 screen]

with **iPhone8**

[image: output on iPhone8 screen]

Comment: Is it one UIView over all the buttons?

Comment: please check my updated answer.
I added the screenshots too. for explain my answers.
in my example Buttons  are having opacity, and UIView are having coloured to show, you can clear the color for both the elements then you will have your solutions.

Comment: Thank you so much..This really will help

Comment: If it work for you then accept the answer too ;) .... hahahaha

Answer (score 0):

If you want make UILabel can be clicked, just use UITapGestureRecognizer.

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(labelClicked))
label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
label.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

and make this function for the selector action.

```
@objc func labelClicked() {
   print("label clicked")
}
```